# Problemas guardando datos en una lista de Python

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for

Este es el enunciado.
Ejercicio 10:
Programa una función que dada una String te devuelva un Array de textos separados por cierto carácter.
Esto es lo que debe recibir miFuncion('hola que tal', ' ') devolverá ['hola', 'que', 'tal'].
Pero a mi solo me devuelve todas las palabras, salvo la ultima, osea ['hola', 'que'].

```
def separardor(cadena = "Hola que tal", divisor = " "):
    lista = []
    palabra = ""
    array = []
    k = 0
    
    for indice in cadena:
        if indice != divisor:
            palabra += indice
        else:
            lista.append(palabra)
            palabra = ""
        k += 1

    return lista


print(separardor())
```

Se por qué pasa. Al no tener el separador, osea el elemento que marca el final de un elemento, el bucle no guardará la ultima palabra, porque no termina en un separador, en este caso un " "
Aun no se me ocurre una manera de arreglar esto. ¿Alguien puede proponer una solucion?

Answer (score 2):

Este es un problema recurrente en programación: estas en un ciclo consumiendo algo y cuando sales del ciclo, todavía quedan cosas por procesar.

En este caso, vas recorriendo un texto y formando una palabra. Cuando ya la tienes, la agregas a la lista, la limpias, y sigues procesando.

Lo que te falta es revisar la palabra luego que salgas del ciclo:

```
if palabra != "":
    lista.append(palabra)
```

Igual tienes que comprobar la condición (de que haya una palabra), pues puede que el texto original termine en espacio, en cuyo caso el `for` terminara sin ninguna palabra pendiente.
Eso es todo.

#### Demo

```
def separardor(cadena="Hola que tal", divisor=" "):
    lista = []
    palabra = ""
    array = []
    k = 0

    for indice in cadena:
        if indice != divisor:
            palabra += indice
        else:
            lista.append(palabra)
            palabra = ""
        k += 1

    if palabra != "":
        lista.append(palabra)

    return lista


print(separardor())
```

produce:

```
['Hola', 'que', 'tal']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Solución alternativa

Una solución alternativa para este problema es agregar un espacio al final del texto antes de procesarlo. Esto garantiza que todas las palabras se detectaran dentro del `for`:

```
def separardor(cadena="Hola que tal", divisor=" "):
    lista = []
    palabra = ""
    array = []
    k = 0
    cadena += ' '

    for indice in cadena:
        if indice != divisor:
            palabra += indice
        else:
            lista.append(palabra)
            palabra = ""
        k += 1

    return lista
```

No siempre es posible modificar el parámetro para ajustarlo a nuestra conveniencia, pero es una alternativa que produce un código más simple.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Hoy se me ocurrio una solucion tan vulgarmente simple que fue simplemente, agregar el contenido de la variable "divisor" al final, para asegurarme que tome la ultima palabra, basicamente tu solucion alternativa. Igual es bueno conocer otras maneras de resolver el mismo problema.